# notification not received after "minifyEnabled true" in android, Why?

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

my notification receive when build.gradel file
**minifyEnabled false**,
but whenever we change the **minifyEnabled true** notification not received in my signed release APK.
This is my **build.gradel** file,

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.abc.xyz.test"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 10
    versionName "1.0.8"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    signingConfig signingConfigs.brand_champs
}
lintOptions {
    disable 'GoogleAppIndexingWarning'
    warningsAsErrors true
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
 'proguard-rules.pro'
        debuggable false
        jniDebuggable false
        renderscriptDebuggable false
        zipAlignEnabled false
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
        zipAlignEnabled false
        jniDebuggable false
        minifyEnabled false
    }
 }

}
```

Comment: Please share your Receiver code and build configuration

Comment: @Maelig sorry for the  delay, i update my gradel file, please check now

Comment: My receiver is perfect because , i received notification when run application in debug mode  "minifyEnabled false" when i change this "minifyEnabled true" and make build that time notification not received

Comment: I guess proguard is messing around with your classes, check this answer and adapt it to add your classes, then try again https://stackoverflow.com/a/29864309/1243048

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Friends solved the above issue,

this issue was related to class migrate or unused class removed from the code when proguard enable.

We write the keep rules in proguard file, and keep the my all model of the application those are related to notifcation

```
-keepclassmembers class com.xyz.test.model.** {
 *;
}
```

this is my class model "com.xyz.test.model.**", you have any different class, according to your id and package name